# Wye to delta transformation

Tags: y-to-delta

I'm trying to find a more intuitive equation for wye to delta formations (going from delta to wye, the traditional equations make sense to me). I came up with the following solution, but I'm not 100% this is useable. Can someone check my work and let me know of any errors?

Side quest: let me know if there's any better way to format this.

Starting from the wye to delta equations:

$$R_1  R_a= R_1  R_2 + R_2  R_3 + R_1  R_3$$

$$R_2  R_b= R_1  R_2 + R_2  R_3 + R_1  R_3$$

$$R_3  R_c= R_1  R_2 + R_2  R_3 + R_1  R_3$$

Using the first equation for this example:

gives $$R_a = (R_1  R_2 + R_2  R_3 + R_1  R_3)/R_1$$
$$ = (R_1  R_2/R_1 + R_2  R_3/R_1 + R_1  R_3/R_1)$$

$$ = (R_1  R_2R_3/R_1R_3 + R_2  R_3R_1/R_1R_1 + R_1  R_3R_2/R_1R_2)$$

$$ = R_1R_2R_3/R_1 * (1/R_3 +1/R_1+1/R_2)$$
$$R_a= R_2R_3 * (1/R_3 +1/R_1+1/R_2)$$

Using the following labeling (diagram from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biomymZbK-U):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### direct answers

> Can someone check my work and let me know of any errors?

I think your equations are fine. I don't see any errors.

> let me know if there's any better way to format this.

I think whatever works for you is better. I don't see any obvious choice, one way or another. Some will prefer one, others another.

> I'm trying to find a more intuitive equation for wye to delta
> formations

I can't say what's more intuitive for you. And if this is just a question about which algebraic form "looks better" then I'm stuck there. But there is [this page](https://spinningnumbers.org/a/delta-wye-derivations.html) that you might skim.

I can add these thoughts:

#### \$\Delta\$ and **Y** KCL

Here's your diagram with \$N_{_\text{Y}}\$ and a few currents added to it:

[image]

In the following, I'll be using conductances for everything. So \$G_1=\frac1{R_1}\$, etc.)

From KCL we can make the following initial observation about the **Y**:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{Y}}\cdot G_1+V_{_\text{Y}}\cdot G_2+V_{_\text{Y}}\cdot G_3 &=V_1\cdot G_1+V_2\cdot G_2+V_3\cdot G_3
\\\\
\therefore\quad V_{_\text{Y}}&=\frac{V_1\cdot G_1+V_2\cdot G_2+V_3\cdot G_3}{G_1+ G_2+G_3}
\end{align*}$$

The net node currents given in the above diagram for each configuration is:

$$\begin{array}{lcccc}
&\textbf{Y}&&&\Delta\\\\
I_1:&\left(V_1-V_{_\text{Y}}\right)\cdot G_1 &&& \left(V_1-V_3\right)\cdot G_{_\text{B}}+\left(V_1-V_2\right)\cdot G_{_\text{C}}
\\\\
I_2:&\left(V_2-V_{_\text{Y}}\right)\cdot G_2 &&& \left(V_2-V_1\right)\cdot G_{_\text{C}}+\left(V_2-V_3\right)\cdot G_{_\text{A}}
\\\\
I_3:&\left(V_3-V_{_\text{Y}}\right)\cdot G_3 &&& \left(V_3-V_2\right)\cdot G_{_\text{A}}+\left(V_3-V_1\right)\cdot G_{_\text{B}}
\end{array}$$

But \$V_{_\text{Y}}\$ can be expanded and then the above can be re-arranged as follows:

$$\begin{array}{lcccc}
&\textbf{Y}&&&\Delta\\\\
I_1:&\frac{\left(V_1\,\left[G_2+G_3\right]-V_2\:G_2-V_3\:G_3\right)\, G_1}{G_1+G_2+G_3} &&& V_1\cdot\left(G_{_\text{B}}+G_{_\text{C}}\right)-V_2\cdot G_{_\text{C}}-V_3\cdot G_{_\text{B}}
\\\\
I_2:&\frac{\left(V_2\,\left[G_3+G_1\right]-V_3\:G_3-V_1\:G_1\right)\, G_2}{G_1+G_2+G_3} &&& V_2\cdot\left(G_{_\text{C}}+G_{_\text{A}}\right)-V_3\cdot G_{_\text{A}}-V_1\cdot G_{_\text{C}}
\\\\
I_3:&\frac{\left(V_3\,\left[G_1+G_2\right]-V_1\:G_1-V_2\:G_2\right)\, G_3}{G_1+G_2+G_3} &&& V_3\cdot\left(G_{_\text{A}}+G_{_\text{B}}\right)-V_1\cdot G_{_\text{B}}-V_2\cdot G_{_\text{A}}
\end{array}$$

You can now directly compare the left and right columns. By inspection, the following ***must*** be true:

$$\begin{align*}
G_{_\text{A}}&=\frac{G_2\,G_3}{G_1+G_2+G_3}
\\\\
G_{_\text{B}}&=\frac{G_3\,G_1}{G_1+G_2+G_3}
\\\\
G_{_\text{C}}&=\frac{G_1\,G_2}{G_1+G_2+G_3}
\end{align*}$$

#### expanding the topic further

There's a really nice selection of historical papers on the topic, from a modern 2022 perspective, that can be found in the first few paragraphs of [*A degree preserving delta wye transformation with applications to 6-regular graphs and Feynman periods*, by Shannon Jeffries and Karen Yeats, July 29, 2022](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.07764.pdf). I recommend at least skimming the first page there just to get a good list of relevant literature on the topic. (And Karen is the contacting author, if you've a mind for that.)

They cite perhaps the earliest paper on the topic as [*"Equivalence of triangles and three-pointed stars in conducting networks,"* **Electrical World and Engineer**, 34:413–414, 1899 by A. E. Kennelly](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/1899,%20Kennelly,%20The%20Equivalence%20of%20Triangles%20and%20Three-Pointed%20Stars%20in%20Conducting%20Networks.pdf). (I just obtained a public domain copy.)

Another important paper is *"Polyeder und Raumeinteilungen"*, **Enzyklopadie der mathematischen Wissenschaften mit Einschluss ihrer Anwendungen**, 1916 by E. Steinitz.

The above authors are, of course, no longer with us.

Perhaps one of the better living experts on this topic would be Isidoro Gitler. I think he is currently at the *"Center for Research and Advanced Studies of the National Polytechnic Institute".* His doctoral thesis, at the University of Waterloo in 1991, was *"Delta-Wye-Delta Transformations: Algorithms and Applications."* He then published [*"On topological spin models and generalized ∆–Y transformations"*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81174967.pdf) in 2002, followed by [*"On terminal delta-wye reducibility of planar graphs"*](https://www.math.cinvestav.mx/sites/default/files/3termArizona2008-5.pdf), 2011.

If you are looking for important insights, I'd strongly recommend making contact. Your questions would be squarely and directly related to his work and publications. I expect you'd get a favorable response to queries.

Comment: Thank you. That is quite a bit more information than I expected. I'll take a look over it when I have more time.

Comment: @Gneiss Part of your question seemed open-ended to me. But I separated the direct answers from the broader reaching ones.  :)